# Attempting to run Django with start Apache2 mod_wsgi on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx without success

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, python, django, wsgi

I have a small [vps](/questions/tagged/vps) with a minimum install of [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) [lucid-lynx](/questions/tagged/lucid-lynx) with about 256mb memory, it's newly installed with nothing special running on it. I'm trying to deploy [django](/questions/tagged/django) to it, while I'm successfully running the server using manage.py, I can't get [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) with [wsgi](/questions/tagged/wsgi) working:

```
# service apache2 start && service apache2 status
* Starting web server apache2                      [ OK ] 
Apache is NOT running.
```

Erorr log `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Thu Apr 14 21:17:29 2011] [warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Apr 14 21:17:29 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/2.8 Python/2.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 14 21:17:29 2011] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[Thu Apr 14 21:17:29 2011] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1216795792,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Thu Apr 14 21:17:29 2011] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[Thu Apr 14 21:17:29 2011] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1216795792,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Thu Apr 14 21:17:31 2011] [alert] No active workers found... Apache is exiting!
```

My [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) config file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/deals/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory /usr/local/django/deals/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The `/usr/local/django/deals/apache/django.wsgi` file:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/usr/local/django/deals'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'deals.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Seem to be installed:

```
# dpkg -l \*apache\* |grep -E '^ii'
ii  apache2                          2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4                        Apache HTTP Server metapackage
ii  apache2-mpm-worker               2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4                        Apache HTTP Server - high speed threaded mod
ii  apache2-utils                    2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4                        utility programs for webservers
ii  apache2.2-bin                    2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4                        Apache HTTP Server common binary files
ii  apache2.2-common                 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.4                        Apache HTTP Server common files
ii  libapache2-mod-wsgi              2.8-2ubuntu1                             Python WSGI adapter module for Apache
```

Comment: Can you include the output of this command? `dpkg -l \*apache\* |grep -E '^ii'`

Comment: @dimmer - Added. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve this. First of I trouble upgrading [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) to [10.10](/questions/tagged/10.10) from [10.04](/questions/tagged/10.04) because the server only offered 128mb (256mb burstable) and ran out mid upgrade. Maybe the solution to this issue is to simply upgrade [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu). I did however upgrade [mod-wsgi](/questions/tagged/mod-wsgi) by installing it from source as [described here](http://tiddlyspace.com/bags/cdent_public/tiddlers/Upgrading%20mod_wsgi), but that didn't seem to affect anything.

The breakthrough came when I installed [apache2-mpm-prefork](/questions/tagged/apache2-mpm-prefork) through `apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork` so it would use that instead of [apache-mpm-worker](/questions/tagged/apache-mpm-worker) as [dimmer](https://serverfault.com/users/60525/dimmer) suggested. I'm unsure if the issue was that having [apache-mpm-worker](/questions/tagged/apache-mpm-worker) was causing my other errors not to be logged, maybe the next person who encounters issue can try skipping this step. When I switched to [apache-mpm-worker](/questions/tagged/apache-mpm-worker) the [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) error log gave the following errors instead.

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=1436): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/django/deals/apache/django.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
     self._setup()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
 ImportError: Could not import settings 'deals.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named deals.setting
```

This is because we were unable to import the settings module. The [wsgi integration with Django documentation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) explained that I need to add include paths, once I updated `/usr/local/django/deals/apache/django.wsgi` everything ran smoothly.

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/django/deals')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/django')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'deals.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an old mod_wsgi bug. Update mod_wsgi to a newer version.

Comment: That would mean upgrading to ubuntu 10.10 - not a bad idea anyway if you can. Another option is to remove apache-mpm-worker and install apache2-mpm-prefork if you don't need threading. Apparently django is not entirely thread-safe and it's recommended you use prefork anyway.

Comment: After struggling with installing [tag:Maverick] on 256 mb burstable ram. I manually installed mod_wsgi from source via this: http://tiddlyspace.com/bags/cdent_public/tiddlers/Upgrading%20mod_wsgi but I'm getting the same error. Going to try dimmers suggestion next.